# Trouble parsing json with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I wrote a quick script to parse two fairly large json file (~17k records) to do a comparison of the two. I have confirmed they are both valid json (via jsonlintpro) and the same format. (The source is the same so this should be a given. But, I always assume the mistake is mine. And I still do. Just somewhere else.) However, the parsed file just outputs [object, Object]. I'm wondering what the cause could possibly be?

The json format is like this small snippet (anonymized of course):

```
[
{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "Name1",
    "url": "https://localhost/Name1",
    "date_created": "2013-07-05T18:47:05Z",
    "date_cancelled": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "id": "54321",
            "type": "Client",
            "value": "General Store"
        },
        {
            "id": "65432",
            "type": "Contact_Name",
            "value": "Joe Smith"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "23456",
    "name": "Name2",
    "url": "https://localhost/Name2",
    "date_created": "2014-02-27T17:46:43Z",
    "date_cancelled": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "id": "34567",
            "type": "Client",
            "value": "Bait Shop"
        }
    ]
}]
```

And here is the pertinent code:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var recs = require('./prod.json');

printArr(recs);

console.log(recs.length);

function printArr(arr) {
        arr.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item + ", ");
        });
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Ok, so apparently the issue is with my printArr function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong there. I'd like to figure it out because I want to expand upon that so I can print selectively.

Comment: does `console.log(recs.length);` output a non-zero number?

Comment: Yes, it outputs 17005.

Comment: Concatenating an `Object` forces it to a `String`, which [will result in `"[object Object]"`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2). By passing each `Object` as its own argument, `console.log(item)`, they'll be [inspected](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) and rendered in a more useful format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the parsed file just outputs [object, Object].

This is the expected behavior BECAUSE you are concatenating an object with a string.

Try `console.log(item)` instead

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(item);` should indeed print `[object, Object]`, did you try to output its properties instead?

```
function printArr(arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log( item.id, item.name, item.url, item.date_created, item.date_cancelled, item.props, ';');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just export the value from the prod.json file.

*prod.json file*

```
module.exports = [
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Name1"
},

{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "Name1"

}]
```

*elsewhere*

```
var recs = require('./prod.json')
console.log(recs)
```